# Re-queue item for QueueTrigger if condition is not met

Tags: c#, azure-functions, message-queue

I have a queue trigger function that looks like this:

```
[FunctionName(nameof("MyQueueFunction"))]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("queue")] Model model, ILogger logger)
{
   if (model.ID == 0)
   {
      // Ignore message in the queue for now
   }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is re-queue the item if the condition stated is not met.  I know I could just re-serialize the item and put it back on the queue myself, but is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: The Azure Storage Queues are somewhat limited in terms of filtering functionality. I suspect you will need to move to a Service Bus Queue/Topic and use the Queue/Topic filtering. Hoping someone will provide a different suggestion though :)

Comment: This is what I figured.  I thought someone might know a way, but I guess re-queuing is the way forward.  Thanks

Comment: @Kane if you make that an answer, I will give you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, the Azure Storage Queues are somewhat limited in terms of filtering functionality.

I suspect you will need to move to a Service Bus Queue/Topic and use the [Queue/Topic filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters).